# Mariadb Galera 4 upgrade - error No package galera available

Tags: mariadb, galera

I am trying to upgrade to Galera4 on RHEL machine.. My repo looks like this :

```
#MariaDB 10.6 RedHat repository list - created 2023-01-25 16:29 UTC
# https://mariadb.org/download/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = https://mirror.nodesdirect.com/mariadb/yum/10.6/rhel7-amd64
gpgkey=https://mirror.nodesdirect.com/mariadb/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

when I try  yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client galera

i see :

```
No package MariaDB-server available.
  * Maybe you meant: mariadb-server
No package MariaDB-client available.
No package galera available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

tried yum clean too.
Any pointers would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Did you try all lowercase?

Comment: thanks Rick.. I did have to tweek the alphabet cases to get the exact working